# Anyone can help me on peformance of this url? it looks it's loading very slow

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here is the link:
http://www.gbin1.com/gbin1/admin/gbin1app.jsp

i'm using jquery mobile to display the page, but it looks jquery mobile is loading the page very slow. and also it's slow if you click navigation bar. How can i improve the performance?  If i remove jquery mobile code, it's kind of faster.  what's wrong with the jquery mobile?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you load some parts of the html with ajax it will be faster.. I don't know the exact size of the page because it stopped after 400KB

Comment: Actually the backend is running very fast. but it's slow to display in jquery mobile. any ideas?